# Magento 1.9: Print variable value in Mage::Log

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, print

My observer :

```
   public function checkproductinorder($Observer)
    {
        $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
          if($item->getSku() == '600' || '800')
            {
              Mage::log('The selected product list available in order', null, 'matchorder.log');
            }
        }
```

If the SKU's 600 or 800 order how can I print the SKU value in Mage::Log like,

> The selected product list available in order. SKU list : **600**, **800**

Comment: Both of the below solutions working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code in your observer, it'll work for you.

```
public function checkproductinorder($Observer)
{
    $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $skus = array('600','800'); //product SKUs
    $skuList = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
      if(in_array($item->getSku(), $skus))
        {
            $skuList[] = $item->getSku();
        }
    }
    if(!empty($skuList)) {
        Mage::log('The selected product list available in order '.implode(',',$skuList), null, 'matchorder.log');
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code will add the SKUs list in one line for an order.

Comment: Bro you edited your answer after my answer. I answered because your answer will not print sku list in comma separated way in logs otherwise I won't answer it in this question. Anyways +1 for sportsmanship

Comment: Yes, I've changed my code after your code as it is more optimized then mine. Also, as Zus mentioned, instead "or" operator in_array is better performance and 100's of SKU list is good to use with an array.

 +1 for your answer for the way it is written.

Comment: Every time observer running with empty value if condition not matching-> https://justpaste.it/2vsv6 how to make observer run only if condition matching? Is this possible?

Comment: I've updated my code, please have a review.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
public function checkproductinorder($Observer)
{
    $order = $Observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $skus = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) 
    {
      if($item->getSku() == '600' || $item->getSku() == '800')
        {
         $skus[] = $item->getSku();
        }
    }
    Mage::log('The selected product list available in order. SKU list: '.implode(",",$skus), null, 'matchorder.log');

}
```

It will print the sku list in comma separated way in log as you mentioned in your question. I hope this will help

Comment: Your solution is good and working, but instead "or" operator in_array is better performance and 100's of sku list is good to used with array right?

Comment: I think you have only two skus for more than two skus `in_array` is better choice. He edited his answer after my answer for sku list anyways no worry

Comment: I really appreciate your mature, thank you for your knowledge sharing. Instead of more number of values your solution is best.

Comment: Every time observer running with empty value if condition not matching-> https://justpaste.it/2vsv6 how to make observer run only if condition matching? Is this possible?

Comment: May i know how to do it in Magento 2.3? @Muhammad Hasham thanks you.